# In navigation be first image

Tags: html, css, image, navigation

I have on website navigation and I would put in image. If i enter image code the image will on the end, and I want if the image be on start navigation (before Link 1).
Here´s my code with CSS:

```
<div class="topnav">
 <img src="https://cdn.mos.cms.futurecdn.net/fHBA4cnnUNMz7pet6GVpSe.jpg" alt="logo" width="100" height="100">
   <a class=active href="home.html">Homepage</a>
   <a href="link.html">Link 1</a>
  <a href="link.html">Link 2</a>
  <a href="link.html">Link 3</a>
  <a href="link.html">Link 4</a>
  <a href="link.html">Link 5</a>

</div>

<div style="padding-left:16px">
  
</div>
<style>
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.topnav {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: orange;
}

.topnav a {
  float: left;
  color: #f3f3f3;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.topnav a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}

.topnav a.active {
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
}
</style>


Please help me how I put image on navigation start. Thank´s for responses!
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't added any CSS to tell the image where to go.

i made a quick nav to give you an idea

https://codepen.io/courtneypunx/pen/eYBjdwp

```
.topnav {
 display: block;
 overflow: hidden;
 background-color: orange;
}
`
`.left{
 float: left;
 margin-left: 25px;
}`

`.right{
 float:right;
 margin-top: 2em;
}`
```

Comment: Thanks, it helped me and I have a logo where I wanted it.